# How do I deploy a Flask application in IIS?

Tags: python, iis-6, wsgi, flask, isapi-wsgi

Can anyone help me get a Flask application running on IIS 6?  I have tried to use isapi-wsgi, but when I visit the Virtual Directory address I get a page that says "The specified module could not be found."  Are there other options for this?

Below is the Python script I wrote for isapi-wsgi.  The Virtual Directory was made and everything looked ok in IIS Manager, but the site did not work.

```
from wof import app
import os

app.secret_key=os.urandom(24)

import isapi_wsgi
def __ExtensionFactory__():
    return isapi_wsgi.ISAPISimpleHandler(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from isapi.install import *
    params = ISAPIParameters()
    sm = [ScriptMapParams(Extension="*", Flags=0)]
    vd = VirtualDirParameters(Name="WOFPy_Sondes", Description="ISAPI-WSGI for WOFPY Sondes test", ScriptMaps=sm, ScriptMapUpdate="replace")
    params.VirtualDirs = [vd]
    HandleCommandLine(params)
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

## High Level Overview

HTTP -> IIS -> ISAPI -> FastCGI -> WSGI (Flask application)

---

## Setup Steps

### Step 1: Install Required Binaries

1. Install Python (2.7 or 3.x -- I used 3.3)
2. Install pip-Win (I used version 1.6)
3. Install pywin32 (I used version 218)
4. Install the IIS FastCGI extension with [fcgisetup 1.5](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/fastcgi-for-iis)

### Step 2: Install Optional Binary Packages

I installed `pyodbc` using the installer .exe from [this site](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/downloads/list). Installing from source (e.g. pip, for installing into a virtual environment) requires a C/C++ compiler.

### Step 3: Get a Copy of `wfastcgi.py`

Choose a version that will work for you, preferably one that supports Python 3.3 (I used [David Ebbo's](https://gist.github.com/davidebbo/6996671)).  You may want the "official" version [from here](https://pytools.codeplex.com/releases/view/103102).

Install the `wfastcgi.py` script into `C:\Inetpub\wwwroot` and make sure the account that will serve your application ("Network Service" by default) has read access to it.

### Step 4: Install `virtualenv` Into the System site-packages

```
C:\Python33\Scripts\pip.exe install virtualenv
```

(if you are using Python 3.3 and installed everything in the default location)

### Step 5: Install Your Flask Application

- You may install the application just about anywhere on the system.  You may want to install it under `C:\Inetpub`.  For this tutorial, we'll call the root folder of your application install  `%APPROOT%`.  (Don't put quotation marks in the environment variable.)
- Make sure that the account that will serve your application ("Network Service" by default) has read access to all of the script files.  This command:

  ```
  cacls "%APPROOT%" /S:"D:PAI(A;OICI;FA;;;BA)(A;OICIIO;FA;;;CO)(A;OICI;0x1200a9;;;NS)(A;OICI;FA;;;SY)"
  ```

  will give your application directory the following permissions:

  - BUILTIN\Administrators: Full control of this folder, subfolders, and files
  - CREATOR OWNER: Full control for subfolders and files only
  - NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE: Read permissions for this folder, subfolders, and files
  - NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM: Full control of this folder, subfolders, and files
- Add any local configuration necessary (my application uses a local.cnf file that is ignored by the version control system) -- e.g. database URLs.
- Make sure your application contains a `Web.config` file in `%APPROOT%` -- see the section below for information on the file format.

### Step 6: Create a virtualenv For Your Application

```
C:\Python33\Scripts\virtualenv.exe --system-site-packages "%APPROOT%\env"
```

(Pick a name other than `env` if your application already uses that directory.)

### Step 7: Install The Packages Required By Your Application to the virtualenv

```
cd "%APPROOT%"
env\Scripts\activate
pip install -r Packages
```

(My project keeps the requirements spec in a file named `Packages`.)

### Step 8: Create a Web Site Or Virtual Directory For Your Application

Use `inetmgr.msc` (*Start* -> *Run…*, then enter `inetmgr` in the edit box and press *ENTER*) to launch *Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager*.  Make sure to set the local path for the node (Web Site or Virtual Directory) you create to the root folder of your Flask application.  `wfastcgi.py` uses the local path to identify the Flask application to handle the requests.

Give both **Read** and Script (**Run Scripts**) permissions for the node.

### Step 9: Configure `fcgiext.ini`

This file is located in the same directory as the `fcgiext.dll` installed in Step 1 (by default, `%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\inetsrv`).

In configuring this file, you need several parameters:

- **{site id}**: the numeric Site ID you can find in the detail (right-hand) pane of *Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager* when “Web Sites” is selected from the tree on the left side of the window.
- **{application name}**: the name of the section within `fcgiext.ini` that provides the parameters for the FastCGI (ISAPI) handler.  You choose this value -- select something that represents your application.
- **{path to app}**: for a Virtual Directory, the URL path within the Web Site to the Virtual Directory to be handled.
- **{approot}**: the path to the root directory of your application.

Use those parameters to:

- Map the FastCGI requests to a handling section:

  - For a whole Web Site, add `*:{site id}={application name}` to the `[Types]` section.
  - For a Virtual Directory, add `*:/lm/w3svc/{site id}/root/{path to app}={application name}` to the `[Types]` section.
- Add a handling section (`[{application name}]`) with parameters for this application ([full reference](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/configuring-the-fastcgi-extension-for-iis-60)):

  - `ExePath={approot}\env\python.exe`
  - `Arguments=C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\wfastcgi.py` (or wherever the `wfastcgi.py` adapter script is installed)
  - `EnvironmentVars=ENV_VAR1:value,ENV_VAR2:value,etc.` (see the full reference for quoting rules).  This is a good place to set your [WSGI_LOG environment variable](http://pytools.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=wfastcgi) -- make sure the account serving the site (“Network Service” by default) has write permissions for the file and (if the file doesn’t exist) permission to add a file to the containing directory.

### Step 10: Configure FastCGI Handling for the Target URLs

Using *Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager*, select “Properties...” from the context (right-click) menu of the node (Web Site or Virtual Directory) to be served by your Flask application and:

- In the “Home Directory” tab (Web Site) or “Virtual Directory” tab (Virtual Directory), click the “Configuration..." button.
- In the “Wildcard application maps” section, use the “Insert..." button to add a wildcard mapping:

  - The executable is the FastCGI extension DLL installed in Step 1.  Its default location is `%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\inetsrv\fcgiext.dll`.
  - Make sure “Verify that file exists” is **unchecked**.  Flask applications do their own routing that doesn’t necessarily have anything to do with the files on the disk.

---

## Web.config

This file is (in this setup) read by `wfastcgi.py`, **not** by IIS.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration>
    <applicationSettings>
        <add key=“PYTHONPATH” value=“”/>
        <add key=“WSGI_HANDLER” value=“module.application”/>
    </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

- `<add>` elements add environment variables (`os.environ` in Python).
- `WSGI_HANDLER` must be specified -- it tells `wfastcgi.py` how to locate the WSGI application object.  If the value ends in "()", `wfastcgi.py` will call the named object, expecting it to return a WSGI application object.
- `PYTHONPATH` is handled specially -- `wfastcgi.py` performs (environment) variable expansion (using the Windows standard `%VAR%` notation) on the value of `PYTHONPATH`, then splits the result at semicolons and appends the entries to `sys.path` before invoking the WSGI application.  Because `wfastcgi.py` changes the current directory to the path specified as the local path of the Web Site or Virtual Directory before importing the module containing the WSGI application object, including an empty string in the PYTHONPATH will cause the search to include your Flask application directory as a starting point.  You can also set PYTHONPATH in `fcgiext.ini` (in which case it is included in `sys.path` by the interpreter and then again by `wfastcgi.py`).
- `WSGI_RESTART_FILE_REGEX` gives a Python regular expression used to filter file-change notifications for paths that should trigger FastCGI handler process restarts.  Set this to trigger when source files or configuration files change.  I use `(?i).*\.(py|cnf|config)$`.
- `WSGI_LOG` may be set here, but I think it is better set in `fcgiext.ini`.

---

## For IIS 7

Some things with FastCGI changed dramatically with IIS 7.  Beginning with this version, FastCGI has support directly through IIS and is not configured through an extension (i.e. Step 1.4 is not necessary and `fcgiext.ini` does not control FastCGI behavior for IIS 7+ and there is no need to create/edit it).  Instead, make sure that **CGI** is enable under **Internet Information Services** in **Control Panel > Programs and Features > Turn Windows Features on or off**.

#### `Web.config`

IIS 7 is the first version of IIS to read configuration settings related to FastCGI from the `Web.config` file.  Your `Web.config` file will need to contain, within the `<configuration>` element, a `<system.webServer>` element containing a `<handlers>` element containing an `<add>` element with the attributes:

- path: `*`
- verb: `*`
- modules: `FastCgiModule`
- resourceType: `Unspecified`
- requireAccess: `Script`
- scriptProcessor: *the tricky one*

#### The `scriptProcessor` Attribute

This attribute of the `<add>` element must contain the full path to the Python interpreter `.exe` file you want to use (the one in the `Scripts` subfolder of your Python virtualenv) followed by a `|` and then the full path to the `wfastcgi.py` file you are using.  As these paths are dependent on the setup of the machine on which your app is running, you may want to have this attribute set as part of your deployment process.

#### IIS Server-wide Set Up

- In `inetmgr`, click on the server node in the tree and then choose *FastCGI Settings* from the center pane.  A list of executable/argument pairs will come up.
- Add an entry for the full paths to your `python.exe` and the `wfastcgi.py` you are using.  Both should be given the same way they show up in the `<handlers>/<add>` element in your `Web.config`.
- Make sure to set up the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable in the new FastCGI application entry to include the root of your application codebase.  The advice about adding an empty `PYTHONPATH` entry in the `<applicationSettings>` of your `Web.config` may not apply to this version of IIS.

Comment: This is a great summary, only minor tweak given changes in windows server/ IIS in the past 6 years is that the default user is now IIS_USRS not Network Service anymore.

You may need to unlock sections of the config with appcmd located in C:\windows\system32\inetsrv, using the command `appcmd unlock config /section:handler`

Comment: Is it possible to run multiplethread under single worker process? Because when I deployed the app it was creating new python process for every request

Comment: > According to the IIS FastCGI configuration file (fcgiext.ini), "each process in the pool will handle one request at a time. After each request, the process will be returned to the pool to await another request."

https://forums.iis.net/t/1147857.aspx?All+requests+to+one+single+FastCGI+process+concurrently+

Answer (score 3):

Check out Django's page on the subject. It helped me set up a working Django project, but it shouldn't be that different for a Flask app.

http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DjangoOnWindowsWithIISAndSQLServer

Comment: ARE YOU SURE FOR YOUR ANSWER?

Answer (score 0):

I never use IIS, but IIS supports CGI gateway, therefore you should be able to adapt CGI with WSGI.

```
IIS <--> CGI <--> WSGI
```

To run a WSGI as a CGI script, you can use the [CGIHandler](http://docs.python.org/library/wsgiref.html#wsgiref.handlers.CGIHandler) in Python standard library.

Comment: CGI is not an acceptable solution unless it's a **very** low-traffic thing (e.g. just used by yourself). It starts a process everytime a page is requested.