# Bokeh Server on IIS Setup

Tags: python, iis, deployment, server, bokeh

I'm trying to figure out how to deploy a Bokeh slider chart over an IIS server.
I recently finished up a Flask application, so I figured I'd try the route where you embed through flask:

https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/howto/server_embed

It's nice and easy when I launch the script locally.. but I can't seem to set it up properly over IIS. I believe the complexity is stemming from the fact that the wfastcgi.py module I'm using to deploy over IIS can't easily multi-thread without some sort of hack-like work around.

So, my second attempt was to wrap the flask app in tornado as below OPTION B
(without much success, but still think this is my best lead here)

[Run Flask as threaded on IIS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37183134/run-flask-as-threaded-on-iis-7)

My third attempt was to try and run Bokeh server standalone on a specific port. I figured I'd be able to run the server via standalone_embed.py using wfastcgi.py on say port 8888 & while using port 5000 for the server callbacks. However, the Server function:

```
from bokeh.server.server import Server
```

still launches it locally on the host machine

```
server = Server({'/': bokeh_app}, io_loop=io_loop, port=5000)
server.start()
```

So this actually works if I go to http://localhost:5000/ on the host,
but fails if I go to http://%my_host_ip%:5000/ from a remote machine.

I even tried manually setting the host but get an "invalid host" error:

```
server = Server({'/': bokeh_app}, io_loop=io_loop, host='%my_host_ip_address_here%:5000')
server.start()
```

**ERR:**

Error occurred while reading WSGI handler: Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\bokeh\server\server.py", line 45, in _create_hosts_whitelist int(parts[1]) ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\WebsitesFlask\bokehTest\wfastcgi.py", line 711, in main env, handler = read_wsgi_handler(response.physical_path) File "C:\WebsitesFlask\bokehTest\wfastcgi.py", line 568, in read_wsgi_handler return env, get_wsgi_handler(handler_name) File "C:\WebsitesFlask\bokehTest\wfastcgi.py", line 537, in get_wsgi_handler handler = **import**(module_name, fromlist=[name_list[0][0]]) File ".\app.py", line 41, in  server = Server({'/': bokeh_app}, io_loop=io_loop, host='%my_host_ip_address_here%:5000') File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\bokeh\server\server.py", line 123, in **init** tornado_kwargs['hosts'] = _create_hosts_whitelist(kwargs.get('host'), self._port) File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\bokeh\server\server.py", line 47, in _create_hosts_whitelist raise ValueError("Invalid port in host value: %s" % host) ValueError: Invalid port in host value: : StdOut: StdErr:

Answer (score 0):

First off, the `--host` parameter should no longer be needed in the next `0.12.5` release. It's probably been the most confusing stumbling block for people trying to deploy a Bokeh server app in a "production" environment. You can follow the discussion on [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/5692) for more details.

---

Looking at the actual implementation in Bokeh that generates the error you are seeing, it is just this:

```
parts = host.split(':')
if len(parts) == 1:
    if parts[0] == "":
        raise ValueError("Empty host value")
    hosts.append(host+":80")
elif len(parts) == 2:
    try:
        int(parts[1])
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError("Invalid port in host value: %s" % host)
```

The exception you are reporting that states that `int(parts[1])` is failing:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\bokeh\server\server.py", line 45, 
in _create_hosts_whitelist int(parts[1]) 
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:
```

So, there is something amiss with the string you are passing for `hosts` that's causing the part after the colon to not be able to be converted to in `int` But without seeing the actual string, it's impossible to say much more. Maybe there is some encoding issue that needs to be handled differently or better. If you can provide a concrete string example that reproduces the problem I can take a closer look.

Comment: Thanks for the response. At the very least, this helps identify was exactly is causing the error. I still haven't figured out how to successfully launch a Bokeh server application via IIS and cannot find any references of anyone successfully doing it & explaining how. However, I did manage to work around the issue & implement dynamic graphics using JS callbacks in a static HTML file: http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html