# Set up IIS to reverse proxy an internal server

Tags: iis, http-proxy

I have a Linux server serving a Flask application with Gunicorn.  I have a separate Windows server with IIS.  Only the IIS server is accessible publicly.  How can I set up IIS as a reverse proxy to my internal server?

Comment: nop: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072166/how-do-i-deploy-a-flask-application-in-iis ? refer to an installation of flask on windows. I need to get flask on linux.

Comment: I have the same problem. All answers I have found are for IIS+Flask on Windows and I would like information for IIS+Flask on Linux.

Comment: ok I will post on it on Server Fault but the the question is not  clearly not a duplicate

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/797705/set-up-iis-to-reverse-proxy-an-internal-server

Comment: Can you use another windows-based proxy?  I don't know if IIS will do reverse proxy - someone may have written a reverse proxy mod for it.